# Syntax error on switch case statement react-redux

Tags: javascript, syntax, react-redux, switch-statement, case

In my code, action.payload points to a todo.index, so my REMOVE_TODO case should filter out a todo if it has the same index as the one the event was fired on. However, I get syntax errors all over. I have messed with my wrappings and even tried rewriting it from scratch but cannot get these syntax errors away. Does someone see something I'm missing here??
Just let me know if any more information is needed please. Thank you all!

```
import { ADD_TODO } from '../constants/action-types'; 
import { REMOVE_TODO } from '../constants/action-types';

const initialState = {
  todos: []
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
    return {
        ...state,
        todos: [...state.todos, action.payload]
    }

    case REMOVE_TODO:
    return {
      ...state,
      todos: [...state.todos.filter((todo, i) => {i  !== action.payload})]
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Will you show what you're getting in error ?

Comment: Yeah it's here `=> {i  !== action.payload})`

on the `=>` equal sign it says expected to return a value in an arrow function.
and on `i  !== action.payload` it says Expected an assignment or function call, instead saw an expression.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Well you missed returning a value inside filter function.**

Have a look at the demo.

```js
const initialState = {
  todos: [1,2,3,7,8,5]
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
    return {
        ...state,
        todos: [...state.todos, action.payload]
    }

    case 'REMOVE_TODO':
    return {
      ...state,
      todos: [...state.todos.filter((todo, i) => i  !== action.payload)]
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

let op = rootReducer({todos:[1,2,3,4,5,6]},{type:'REMOVE_TODO',payload:1});
console.log(op)
```

Comment: Ahhhh I was returning an object from my filter method. That's all it was

Comment: @ColeGonzales Yeah that's what my answers first line is saying :)

Comment: Oh hahaha. I didn't catch the caption 

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was simply returning an object from my filter method. `todos: [...state.todos.filter((todo, i) => {i  !== action.payload})]`
Just took away the curly brackets from the return on the arrow function and it's all good now.